# Elaborar um programa para ler um gabarito com dez questões objetivas python

Tags: python

Elaborar um programa para ler um gabarito com dez questões objetivas fornecido como uma string com dez caracteres relativos às alternativas corretas (cada resposta é indicada por ‘A’ ou 'a', ‘B’ ou 'b', ‘C’ ou 'c', ‘D’ ou 'd' ou ‘E’ ou 'e') . Ex.: Se for digitado "DCBEACDDEA" isto significa que as alternativas corretas são: 1a. questão 'D', 2a. 'C', 3a. 'B', etc. 


Obs. O programa deve repetir a leitura do gabarito completo se este for digitado com algum erro (p.ex., quantidade de questões ou algum caractere inválido). 

Após a leitura do gabarito, o programa lê 5 respostas de provas, também como strings, avalia e escreve a nota de cada uma delas. Cada nota é de 0 a 10 (isto é, determinada por um ponto para cada item da resposta da prova que confere com o gabarito).

 Havendo algum erro na digitação da prova a ser avaliada, o programa escreve uma mensagem informando que não pode atribuir nota por esse motivo. 

Além do programa principal, deve haver funções para:

- leitura do gabarito 

- leitura das respostas 

- avaliação das respostas 

- impressão da nota 

 tentei fazer galera mas não tenho minima ideia como resolver isso, não consegui fazer se alguem puder me ajudar a pelo menos dar uma luz pra como resolvo isso agradeço.

Comment: Ao invés de escrever o programa em Python, você conseguiria escrever o algoritmo em texto corrido que descreve a solução?

Comment: Você quer ler as respostas na imagem digitalizada do gabarito? Se for, não é nem um pouco fácil e você vai precisar estudar visão computacional.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente aqui se respondem dúvidas mais específicas sobre programas ja começados, quando você não sabe para onde ir a partir de um ponto.

Mesmo assim, vou tentar dar algumas dicas: a principal funcionalidade normalmente 
negligenciada por iniciantes em programação, em qualquer linguagem, são as "funções". Você deve ter aprendido como criar e usar uma em Python (com o comando `def`).

A partir daí, se você dividir cada coisa diferente que seu programa tem que fazer para uma função - o menor possível, e juntar uma função principal para "orquestrar" a chamada das outras, a coisa começa a ficar mais simples.

Mesmo para o programa "falar com o mundo" - nesse caso, ler strings digitadas e imprimir respostas, ele usa funções. No caso, são as funções pré-definidas (em inglês "builtin") do Python: `print` e `input` (você também deve ter aprendido).

Com funções, o comando para o laço de repetição `for`, e o comando para executar código dependendo de uma condição (`if`) dá pra fazer qualquer programa.  E falo inclusive programas que servem páginas web, desenham janelas, de jogos, etc... - a única diferença é que nesses casos você vai precisar usar funções (as vezes de terceiros) para "falar" com o mundo de forma diferente. ( Funções para criar um campo de texto numa janela, e ler o que for digitado lá, em vez de `input` que só lê do terminal, por exemplo).

Claro que a linguagem Python e todas as outras vão *muito* além do `def`, `for` e `if` -  e isso permite criar programas mais curtos, mais expressivos, mais organizados. Mas com esses 3 você faz tudo.

Então nesse caso, você deve começar a pensar num esqueleto do seu programa - e em seguida o que vai fazer cada função. Se não entendeu bem como uma função recebe parâmetros e devolve um resultado - isso você precisa estudar. Recomendo usar o Python no modo interativo.

```
def ler_gabarito(comprimento, alternativas):
   correto = True
   entrada = input("Digite o gabarito: ")
   if len(entrada) != comprimento:
       print(f"São {comprimento} questões! Digite o número certo de respostas")
       correto = False
   for letra in entrada:
       if letra not in alternativas:
            print(f"A letra {letra}  não é uma alternativa válida")
            correto = False
   if correto:  # (nunca precisa fazer 'variavel == True')
       return entrada
   # se não estiver bom, chama a mesma função de novo e retorna seu resultado
   return ler_gabarito(comprimento, alternativas)   

def le_resposta(gabarito):
   ...
   nota = 0
   for i in range(len(gabarito)):
       ...
   print(nota)

def principal():
    gabarito = ler_gabarito(..., ...)
    for i in range(5):
       le_resposta(gabarito)

principal()
```

Comment: eu coloquei a prinmeira funçai o inteira - mas ela pode ficar mais simples se você usar o `while`  em vez de apenas `if`  por exemplo. 
Na função que corrige as provas, leia sobre a função `zip` do Python para ficar mais elegante.